# Why am I getting a segfault with this code when using snprintf?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am working on a simple web server in C, and whenever I try to write to a char[] that I have declared in main in another function, I am getting a segfault. Before anyone suggests, I have not declared it as a string literal. I have tried allocating with malloc(), setting every char in the array to the null terminator on initialization, and not initializing it to anything (i.e. it is not read until something new is written to it, so there is not a reason to zero it to anything initially), all to no avail.

The syntax of what is going on is as follows:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 20

int some_function(char *buffer) { //many other params as well
    //lots of other code 
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, "%s", "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // This is where the segfault is thrown
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    //many other declarations
    //...
    some_function(buffer);
}
```

The odd thing is, is the segfault only occurs the first time that I call the write to the buffer with a specific syntax. There are some requests that do not create a segfault. If I submit the requests that cause the segfault after the ones that do not, they no longer cause a segfault. Any insight?

Comment: `char *buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];` --> `char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];`

Comment: Read your compiler error messages. If you don't see any, you need to reconfigure your compiler

Comment: sorry, I actually had a typo in what I asked above. It isn't an array of pointers; I've altered the code to reflect what I have that is giving me the problem. Also, for anyone wondering, I am compiling with -Wall.

Comment: The problem is in the code you're not showing, which is almost certainly too much code to add to your question. You'll have to run it through a debugger and/or Valgrind and see what's actually happening.

Comment: 1) Do you get the failure with the _posted_ code? 2) Do you use `MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH` anywhere else given its suspicious name? - I'd expect `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` for `char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];`and thus expect improper usage elsewhere as string _lengths_ are 1 less than needed array _sizes_

Comment: 1) I have not run the posted code, but the real kicker is that I have various other arrays that I am using in EXACTLY the same manner and there is no problem with them at all.
2) I will double check for correct definition. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your buffer is not an array of characters.  It's an array of character **pointers**.  Your compiler should have warned you about the type mismatch.

Change the declaration to:

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
```

Comment: Only if you compile with warnings on.  Which should be mandatory prior to posting a question on SO.

Comment: @dave: It actually is advised on the info page. But it apparently is not read by many askers. Maybe there should be some checks mandatory for question with the C (or other) tag before posting.

Comment: It would be advisable to pass the buffer size to the function so `some_function` does not have to make a wild guess about the buffer size.

Comment: sorry, I actually had a typo in what I asked above. It isn't an array of pointers; I've altered the code to reflect what I have that is giving me the problem. Also, for anyone wondering, I am compiling with -Wall.